# Risks of using php.ini-development as the default php.ini

Tags: php, default

So, while developing stuff using php, I backup the original `php.ini` and rename and use the `php.ini-development` at the `php.ini` file.
After I am done, I restore the default `php.ini`.

Now, my question is this: What are the drawbacks and risks or continuing to use the `php`.ini-development` as the normal php configuration file.

Might be a dumb question but I am a PHP novice.